# jQuery + JSONP return empty data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

Ok for some reason my script does not return any data from a JSON file witch is being fetched from 3rd party site.

Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var url =  "http://konachan.net/post/index.json?limit=20&tags=hatsune_miku";
    $.getJSON(url + "&callback=?", null, function(items) {
        for(i in items) {
            item = items[i];
                        $("#content").append('<div class="product" id="product-' + item.id + '"><img src="' + item.preview_url + '" width="135" height="138"/><div class="title">' + item.author + '</div><div class="description" style="overflow:hidden;">' + item.tags + '</div><div class="clear"></div></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

What the heck is wrong with it?

Edit: PHP Curl still no work: http://pastebin.com/5gVUviZw

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DM77K/ -- See the error data in your console when you load this JSFiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hit the url http://konachan.net/post/index.json?limit=20&tags=hatsune_miku&callback=test with a callback parameter, and I do not see the JSON wrapped in a function name.

The way JSONP works is when you pass a callback function name, the server should wrap the JSON in that function so that when the JavaScript is returned from the server, the callback function is called, and the JSON data is passed in as a parameter.

```
// "test" was the callback parameter I used
test({ "my": "data" , "returned_from" : "server" });
```

*Under the hood, JSONP uses script elements to download the JavaScript (JSON) from the remote server.*

Since the JSON in your url isn't being wrapped in a function name, you can't get easy cross-domain access to it. Here is the [Wikipedia Article on JSON with Padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP), which explains in more detail.

Perhaps you might check the documentation of that particular resource, as it's quite possible they're using a parameter other than "callback" to specify a callback function to "pad" the data with.

If there is no parameter to wrap the result in a function name, you could use a server-side proxy to obtain the JSON response and wrap it up in a function, which you then return to the client side.

Comment: there is no callback function for json so i dough it its just "page", "limit" and "tags"

Comment: how would i use server side proxy?

Comment: server side proxy is a great idea in this case, as your resource doesn't seem to support crossdomain ajax cals/jsonp.  Basically (on your server) you would load the url data and print it out to screen, so that you dont have to go crossdomain to get it through javascript.

Comment: Then, once you've written code that prints that to the screen, you use *your* url in the `getJSON` call. So essentially, your JavaScript calls your server, and then your server goes out to konachan to get the JSON data for you.

Comment: @jmort253 ok i am lost.. at this point and possibly hit a brick wall here is a code paste: http://pastebin.com/5gVUviZw for curl-ing the resource into PHP yet no luck

Comment: That does look like it will work, assuming PHP is what you're using server side :) I'm also assuming you're going to change the url on the first line so that it's using the konachan url...

Answer (score 1):

Because the code returned from the 3rd party site is obviously not made for a JsonP call - it just returns an array with data like `[]`. But it should return this array and invoke a js function so your script can access the data like `myCallbackFunc([])`.

Search for `jsonp` on this page for more info http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: alright what would i need to do to push this into XML format? just replace .json in the url to .xml or would it face the same problem as JSON?

Comment: @cl - You're still facing the same trouble. With XML you are even more limited. You can't make cross domain AJAX calls. Your only option is either buried in the documentation (i.e find the parameter to use to get the padding/function wrapper) or use a server-side proxy to get the JSON and wrap a function around it.